# How to check if a value is larger than the average of these values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the a list of people who earn more money than the average salary in their country

```
SELECT e1.first_name || ' ' ||e1.last_name
FROM hr.employees e1
WHERE salary >= (
  Select AVG(salary) 
  FROM HR.employees e2
  INNER JOIN HR.departments ON e2.department_id = departments.department_id
  INNER JOIN HR.locations ON HR.departments.location_id = HR.locations.location_id
  INNER JOIN HR.countries ON HR.locations.country_id = hr.countries.country_id
  GROUP BY hr.countries.country_id
);
```

The subquery gives me the average salary values per country and works right.
However when I try to combine them I get the following error:

ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row

Any idea what I should do to get the query working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AVG` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT full_name
FROM   (
  SELECT e.first_name || ' ' ||e.last_name AS full_name,
         e.salary,
         AVG( e.salary ) OVER ( PARTITION BY l.country_id ) AS avg_salary
  FROM   hr.employees e
         INNER JOIN HR.departments d
         ON e.department_id = d.department_id
         INNER JOIN HR.locations l
         ON d.location_id = l.location_id
)
WHERE  salary > avg_salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             AVG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY l.country_id) as country_avg
      FROM HR.employees e JOIN
           HR.departments d
           ON e.department_id = d.department_id JOIN
           HR.locations l
           ON d.location_id = l.location_id
     ) e
WHERE e.salary >= e.country_avg;
```

Note that the `country` table is not needed.  The `country_id` is sufficient to identify the country.